# select2 plugin not working inside a popup

Tags: jquery, html, blockui, jquery-select2

I have been working the select2 plugin for a while now and until now its been perfect.

I have a page with 3 selects that are loading data and working well, and multiple selects that are inside the popup. They are looking good but you can't write on the search field.
in the main page the search is working well so i can't figure out what is the problem..

I'm workign with the blockUI plugin for the popup. I have tried z-index, destroy and starting the plugin on a callback for the blockUI function but nothing is working and I have no idea why.

the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ff</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.2/select2.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.2/select2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://xiao3meng.googlecode.com/files/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".startselect").select2();

            $('#clickstartpopup').click(function() { 
                $.blockUI({ 
                    message: $('#popblock'),
                    onBlock: function() { 
                        $(".popupselect").select2();

                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="maincontent1" class="maincontent mywebsitepage">
  <select  class="startselect" id="merchantList">
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
     <option value="saab">Saab</option>
     <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
     <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div style="clear: both; height: 15px;"></div>
<span id="clickstartpopup" style="cursor: pointer;color:red;" >click me!</span>
<div style="height: 300px;background-color: red;display:none;" id="popblock" >
   <select class="popupselect">
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
     <option value="saab">Saab</option>
     <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
     <option value="audi">Audi</option>
   </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: code please  .........!!

Comment: I've used this with twitter bootstrap's modals, and it works inside it. Maybe in some cases you need to add a z-index to the select2 divs, but nothing more :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because of the way Chosen/Select2 works. The actual native controls are still there, but are made invisible so that elements can be overlayed which are styled the way you like them.

In this case, the Select2 elements are rendered outside of `#popblock`, like this:

```
<div class="blockUI blockMsg blockPage" style="z-index: 1001; position: fixed; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 30%; top: 40%; left: 35%; text-align: center; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border: 3px solid rgb(170, 170, 170); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); cursor: wait;">
    <div style="height: 300px; background-color: red;" id="popblock">
        <div class="select2-container popupselect select2-dropdown-open select2-container-active"
        id="s2id_autogen1">
            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">   <span>Volvo</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close" style="display:none;"></abbr>   <div><b></b></div></a>
        </div>
        <select class="popupselect" style="display: none;">
            <option value="volvo">
                Volvo
            </option>
            <option value="saab">
                Saab
            </option>
            <option value="mercedes">
                Mercedes
            </option>
            <option value="audi">
                Audi
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="select2-drop select2-with-searchbox select2-drop-active" style="top: 337px; left: 692px; width: 76px;">
    <div class="select2-search">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="select2-input" style="">
    </div>
    <ul class="select2-results">
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted">
            <div class="select2-result-label">
                <span class="select2-match">
                </span>
                Volvo
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
            <div class="select2-result-label">
                <span class="select2-match">
                </span>
                Saab
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
            <div class="select2-result-label">
                <span class="select2-match">
                </span>
                Mercedes
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
            <div class="select2-result-label">
                <span class="select2-match">
                </span>
                Audi
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The reason that only the search bar seems to not be working is that the search bar is the only UI control that does not have a native counterpart.